# axios basic auth - como passar usuario e senha para a api?

Tags: react, axios

Estava vendo a documentação do axios e vi que para passar o usuário e senha é necessario usar:

```
auth: {
  username: 'janedoe',
  password: 's00pers3cret'
},
```

Apliquei o mesmo no meu código reactjs:

```
axios.get(store.urlBase + 'api/teste?teste=' + teste+ '&teste2=' + teste2,{},{
   auth: {
      Username: 'janedoe',
      Password: 's00pers3cret'
   }
})
```

porem quando chega na api o valor de username e password esta vazio, o que pode ser feito?

Obs: Pelo Postman funciona!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na documentação do axios, o método [get](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosgeturl-config) recebe apenas dois parâmetros: a url e as configurações.

No seu código você está passando três. O seu segundo parâmetro é um objeto vazio ({}) e o axios está utilizando ele para definir as configurações. Assim, basta você chamar o método get da seguinte forma:

```
axios.get('api', {
   auth: { 
      username: 'janedoe', 
      password: 's00pers3cret' 
   }
})
```